# getting string resources from an external library

Tags: android

I have an android app supporting many languages, and there are thousands of strings. Everything works fine, but the problem is if any of those strings gets updated, I'd need to build a new APK.

Is there a way for my app to get the string resources from an external library such that I don't need to install a new apk each time the strings change.

Comment: You could parse them onto your app using a web service

Comment: I forgot to mention, that everything must runs on a device with no internet connectivity, having said that, can I still use a web service?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web service for those strings and returned in json so you can use inside your application.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that everything must runs on a device with no internet connectivity, having said that, can I still use a web service?

Comment: No you cant user service without internet connection but if you know strings value from before in diferent languages you can add them in string folder and update apk.

Comment: The whole idea is to keep the APK intact

Comment: I understand but if you want to achieve this you want internet connection it is not feasible without internet. You can still have same apk and change string from service.

Comment: I'm mostly a c++ programmer, and new to Android. in c++ we can define a dll, and an executable which uses that dll. then as long as we keep the api the same, the same .exe can use a different version of the dll. Can't we do the same thing in Android, where it gets the string resources from an external library, basically every string ID is defined in the strings.xml, and in the application first it checks the external library and if the id exists then it's used, otherwise the one in the strings.xml will be used, is it clear?

Comment: How this dll change? locally or need internet?